# Reducing power to a kettle

Tags: power, control

I have a small (300 W) kettle that just plugs in and is on. It really needs a simmer setting so I could cook soup in there. Is there a simple way to do this? I thought of adding some kind of power reducing switch but don't know what that would be called or how it would work in electrical terms. It would need to be variable so I could find the right setting to simmer.

Comment: I've voted to close this as a repair question even though you technically don't want to _repair_ it, but _modify_ it. The repair-reason is partially there to prevent people who don't know what they're doing to hurt themselves or start random fires, and I think it applies here.

Comment: A variac would do this but is a very expensive solution...

Comment: A lot of things would do this, but let's stop answering questions in comments, which is even _worse_ when it comes to giving electrical advice to inexperienced users.

Comment: I'd expect plug-in dimmer switches to work for this, although if the kettle is "smart" in any way you might find that it refuses to stay on.

Answer (score 2):

You could buy an inline dimmer switch intended for lamps. An example would be the 300W-rated Lutron TT-300H-WH, about $12 US. Make sure it's rated for at least the watts on your kettle nameplate. The one shown below allows you to plug it into the wall and plug the kettle into the back of the dimmer plug.

[image: ![enter image description here]

These devices are very simple- consisting of a triac, diac (sometimes combined) a variable resistor and a capacitor. Sometimes there's a cursory effort to reduce EMI with an inductor and another capacitor. The device will get warm.

---

I would be a bit worried that the kettle will not auto shut off at less than full power. Our Hamilton Beach 40865C (photo from Amazon), for example, does not shut off if the lid is not fully closed so I'm pretty sure it would not shut off under dimmed conditions. The likely consequence of this would be a dead kettle if you let it go dry, but it's always possible it could represent a fire hazard.

[image]

In the old days we just had to pay attention (you plugged the chrome kettle into the wall and made sure to unplug it before it boiled dry- there was not even a switch). But people become dependent on safety features (think of cross-traffic cameras, pedestrian warnings, lane departure warnings, adaptive cruise control etc. on many modern cars).

Comment: The "off" switch is pressed by a bi-metal which curves upon expension from being heated by the steam. That's why the kettle won't turn off with the lid open.

Answer (score 1):

Wire up an incandescent light dimmer that's good for at least 300W.

Comment: thanks. it has a thermostat and no provision for not switching off if the lids not on so I think the dimmer switch is ideal. appreciate your concern for safety! best avi